# ¿Cómo cierro/destruyo una aplicación?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo la siguiente función que inicia una ventana con una barra de carga indeterminada en un archivo llamado **`Barra_carga.py`**.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import Label, ttk
    
    def carga():
        cargando = tk.Tk()
        cargando.title("Barra de progreso en Tk")
        ancho_cargando = 260
        alto_cargando = 100
        x_cargando = cargando.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_cargando // 2
        y_cargando = cargando.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_cargando // 2
        posicion = str(ancho_cargando) + "x" + str(alto_cargando) + "+" + str(x_cargando) + "+" + str(y_cargando)
        cargando.geometry(posicion)
        cargando.resizable(0,0)
        mensaje = Label(cargando,text="Espere por favor").place(x=90,y=20)
        progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(cargando,mode="indeterminate")
        progressbar.place(x=30, y=60, width=200)
        progressbar.start(2)
    
        return cargando
```

Y tengo el siguiente código que inicia un escaneo de archivos de sistema y luego inicia la barra de carga:

```
import subprocess
import Barra_carga

proceso = subprocess.Popen("sfc /scannow", shell=True) 
cargando = Barra_carga.carga
```

Intenté con el siguiente código obtener la respuesta del proceso al finalizar y funciona perfectamente ya que mientras no termina devuelve `None`, pero cuando intento cerrar el proceso de la barra de carga no se cierra a pesar de que ya terminó el proceso.

```
while proceso.poll() == None:
     cargando().mainloop()
else:
     cargando().destroy()
```

He intentado de todo y no logro hacer que se cierre el proceso.

¿Alguna idea de cómo lograrlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podés hacer es inicializar la interfaz, usar el mainloop (que por cierto traba el código hasta que se cierra la ventana) y checkear en otra tarea (esto usando el modulo threading) si el proceso sigue inicializado. Si terminó, entonces es tiempo de cerrar la ventana.

Un código que implementa esto:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, ttk
import subprocess
import threading

def close_if_finish():
    # usamos un while que no hace nada para esperar
    # que deje de cumplirse la condición
    while proceso.poll() == None:
         pass
    root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
proceso = subprocess.Popen(["spotify"])
threading.Thread(target=close_if_finish).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Aclaraciones:

- No está 100% probado. Lo probé haciendo un proceso que abra Spotify y la ventana se cierra inmediatamente, presumiblemente por que el proceso termina antes.
- No uso clases, pero se puede adaptar para que sean usadas.

Comment: Ya intente ese método y la verdad no me dio buenos resultados ya que si pongo la ventana de carga se me congela y si pongo una ventana nueva no entiendo como obtener la ventana de carga para luego cerrarla